# Avro module version mismatch in source code—requires StringIO is which no longer supported in Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, avro

I'm writing a script in Python 3.6 that uses the Avro module to parse some ADS-B messages, which means I'll be using the `avro.datafile.DataFileReader` function. The problem is that when I import DataFileReader like this:

`from avro.datafile import DataFileReader` at the top of my script, I'm met with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reader.py", line 1, in <module>
    from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/avro/datafile.py", line 33, in <module>
    from StringIO import StringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO'
```

From [What's New in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html), I see *"the `StringIO` and `cStringIO` modules are gone. Instead, import the `io` module and use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` for text and data respectively."*

This is where I'm stuck. Should I modify the `avro` module source code to make it python3-compatible?

NOTE: I installed `avro` using `pip3.6 install avro-python3`, so the module believes it is python3-compatible.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error on my end

Comment: Turned out to be an issue with pip not installing the package as it was named, but instead as UNKNOWN==0.0.0. This was fixed with `pip install setuptools --upgrade`. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest writing this as a solution, so other people can find it easily